# visual tool for debugging recursive code

Tags: debugging, recursion

when debugging code which's called recursively many times, sometimes it gets difficult to realize  which execution of the code you are seeing. Is there any IDE graphic tool which helps to see that  with diagrams or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your looking for "Call Stack" in Visual Studio. Other IDEs have similar functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Now this is an very old and already answered topic but Visual Studio has the parallel debugging window which allows you to see the state of your variables. Callstack is typically very hard to track.

See more in [Kaycee Anderson's MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/09/18/7-more-lesser-known-debugging-tactics-for-visual-studio/)

Here is a reference taken from the blog
[image: Parallel Debugging]

Comment: This is really good answer!! Dont know why its not upvaoted for so long. Looks like either people are getting really good at recursion or they dont just use it anymore!